How can I set the properties of a custom created cell with UIListContentConfiguration?
I have created a custom cell, the file for this custom cell is an .xib file (called MessageCell.xib). The .xib file is associated with a .swift file where I can enter the code and in this file I have some IBOutlet properties. What I want to do is to set these properties using UIListContentConfiguration and I don't know how to do it or if it can be set. In the picture below I have implemented this for iOS 14 and later, for older versions I have followed the traditional way. There is nothing wrong with what is written for older versions, but the code I wrote for iOS 14 does not work / gives errors.
This is my specially created cell.
class MessageCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var rightImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var leftImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageBubble: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        messageBubble.layer.cornerRadius = messageBubble.frame.height / 5
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
}

Here I assign a string expression from the messages array to the label property in my cell.
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MessageCell
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *)
        {
            var config = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
            config.text = messages[indexPath.row].body
            cell.contentConfiguration = config
        }
        cell.label.text = messages[indexPath.row].body
        return cell
    }

I achieved many features of the structure through trial and error, but I could not achieve my goal.

Don't post pictures of code. Code is text. Copy it and paste it into your question, and format it as code.

Sorry, I'm correcting

But you're still not giving enough information. "What I want to do is to set these properties using UIListContentConfiguration" what properties? We probably need to see the cell code.

I have a tutorial that might help you: https://www.biteinteractive.com/cell-content-configuration-in-ios-14/

I am new to using Slackoverflow, sorry and thank you for the tutorial you shared. I am updating the post.

Again I say: read my tutorial. You cannot use UIListContentConfiguration for this, so that was a silly restriction to place on the question. Does a UIListContentConfiguration have two images? Does it have a message bubble? No. So you will have to write your own configuration type. And my tutorial shows you how to do it.

Yes, I read your tutorial and got the information I wanted. Thank you for your time.

You cannot use a UIListContentConfiguration for this, because the interface elements you are trying to configure in the cell are not the built-in image-and-title views. You will have to write a custom UIContentConfiguration and UIContentView, responding in the code to the setting of the properties of the configuration by configuring the corresponding interface elements yourself.

For a tutorial, see my https://www.biteinteractive.com/cell-content-configuration-in-ios-14/
